# Where can I find a Buddist Monastery that practice hard training in india?

Tags: meditation-practicalities

I have done 02  10days Vipassana Meditation  (S N Goenkaji)and want to devote life for same. Interested in knowing is any monetary in india where I can stay for years or more and learn teaching of Buddha and Vipassana

Comment: Bhante Piyadhammo http://www.forestdhammatalks.org/en/contact.php

Comment: That link seems to be to a Wat in Thailand? I don't know, there's also a [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/country.php?country_id=42) which might be helpful towards finding local organisations, e.g. in India.

Comment: Bhante Piyadhammo has become international preceptor and it's said that currently monastery is on to be erected in India, as possible first Dhammayut monastery in India.

Answer (score 1):

Following lists out Buddhist monasteries in India: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Buddhist_monasteries_in_India